Reference Request on a Theorem by Woodin
I am looking for a reference of a proof of the following result by Woodin:
If there is a weakly-compact Woodin cardinal (in $V$), then the $L(\mathbb R)$ of $V$ is elementary equivalent to the "Solovay model", that is, the $L(\mathbb R)$ of any forcing extension $V[G]$ for $G$ a $V$-generic filter for the Lévy collapse of any inaccessible cardinal to $\omega_1$.
Is there a better way to state this? The place where I found it told that the proof is in an article by Shelah and Woodin from 1990, but I looked at that article (large cardinals imply that every reasonably refinable set of reals is Lebesgue measurable) and I don't see how the theorems in there imply the result I stated here.

I'd suggest including the actual reference to the Shelah–Woodin paper.
